# Interpreting Residual plots: Linear Regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-visualization, multivariate-analysis, residuals

I created one simple regression model for predicting the amount of loan that needs to be given to a particular individual. I plotted the residual plots to understand the underlying assumptions in the regression. However, I'm not too sure how should I interpret the graph. Could someone please help.

The graph was created using the below code.

```
sns.residplot(y_train_preds,y_train_preds- y_train)
```

Attaching screenshot.[image]

Comment: We will need more information about your data and model to interpret this.

Comment: 1. You're plotting the *negative* of the residuals against fitted? Why? 2. DIscreteness of y-values (or at least y's concentrated at a few specific values) accounts for the banded appearance.

Comment: @mkt, may I know what information is required and I'll add it here.

Comment: @Glen_b are you suggesting `sns.residplot(y_train_preds, y_train-y_train_preds)`

Comment: That would be the more typical thing to do in statistics (to plot $y_i-\hat{y}_i$ vs $\hat{y}_i$), yes so statisticians will generally be more used to reading a plot done that way around.

Comment: The residuals should be calculated as predicted minus observed and not the other way around.